# Correct Interpretation of copula contour plots

Tags: r, data-visualization, fitting, copula, exploratory-data-analysis

Going into exploratory data analysis with the intention of fitting copula models, I was looking at the famous `copula` and they mention [here](https://datascienceplus.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas/) that either contour or 3D plots of both variables, against some third metric, are often used to determine the correct copula to act as a pair for two variables.

Here are [some I have generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDYuo.jpg) from the following copulas: two normal dist.s with 0 and 0.5 correlations, respectively, and two t-dist.s with the same respective correlations, with 10 degrees of freedom.

However, looking at these, how precisely does one interpret them? I have only seen this visual approach taken in this and another copula package, `VineCopula`, and I would like to learn a good resource so I can further read up on this.

Thank you ahead of time for any advice.